# Example of an authorization URL built with client identifier?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm reading [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) which says that:

> The Client ID is a publicly exposed string that is used by the service API to identify the application, and is also used to build authorization URLs that are presented to users.

Can someone give an example (Facebook, Github, ...) of an authorization URL that is presented to the user containing the client identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose digital ocean provides the authorization service and that you have registered your application with them and received a `CLIENT_ID` and `secret`.  An example of a authorization URL using the **authorization code flow** [per the article linked](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) would be:

`https://cloud.digitalocean.com/v1/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=CALLBACK_URL&scope=read`